# Optimizing Dataframe Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, large-data

I have dataset containing details of tasks handled by a team; for each task, different attributes are saved. Based on this dataset, I want to find the time at which an employee picked a new task after closing the current one. The dataframe has following structure (actual dataframe is in million rows):

Following are relevant:

a) Each employee is allowed to work on tasks coming in from certain countries and functions. These  are stored in 'countries' and 'functions' columns. So I need to pick the next task picked by the employee from the last 'countries' and 'functions' values

b) tasks are added into a queue by users from where the employee picks a new task after completing the last.

I want to find the time_assigned value for each row (called reference row for ease), under the following conditions:

a)  for the same employee (employee_id is same as in reference row)

b) lowest time_assigned value higher than time_closed in the reference row

c)  country_code is present in the countries column of d) the reference row

d)  function is present in the functions column of the reference row

Currently I am using the following code

```
data={'task_id' : ['request_1001', 'request_1002', 'request_1003', 'request_1004', 'request_1005', 'request_1006', 'request_1007', 'request_1008', 'request_1009', 'request_1010', 'request_1011', 'request_1012', 'request_1013', 'request_1014', 'request_1015', 'request_1016', 'request_1017', 'request_1018', 'request_1019', 'request_1020', 'request_1021', 'request_1022', 'request_1023', 'request_1024', 'request_1025', 'request_1026', 'request_1027', 'request_1028', 'request_1029', 'request_1030', 'request_1031', 'request_1032', 'request_1033', 'request_1034', 'request_1035', 'request_1036', 'request_1037', 'request_1038', 'request_1039', 'request_1040', 'request_1041', 'request_1042', 'request_1043', 'request_1044', 'request_1045', 'request_1046', 'request_1047', 'request_1048', 'request_1049', 'request_1050', 'request_1051', 'request_1052', 'request_1053', 'request_1054', 'request_1055', 'request_1056', 'request_1057', 'request_1058', 'request_1059', 'request_1060', 'request_1061', 'request_1062', 'request_1063', 'request_1064', 'request_1065', 'request_1066', 'request_1067', 'request_1068', 'request_1069', 'request_1070', 'request_1071', 'request_1072', 'request_1073', 'request_1074', 'request_1075', 'request_1076', 'request_1077', 'request_1078', 'request_1079', 'request_1080', 'request_1081', 'request_1082', 'request_1083', 'request_1084', 'request_1085', 'request_1086', 'request_1087', 'request_1088', 'request_1089', 'request_1090', 'request_1091', 'request_1092', 'request_1093', 'request_1094', 'request_1095', 'request_1096', 'request_1097', 'request_1098', 'request_1099', 'request_1100'],
'function' : ['function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_4', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_6', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_6', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_5', 'function_7', 'function_5', 'function_5', 'function_2', 'function_5', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_7', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_1', 'function_5', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_2', 'function_4', 'function_7', 'function_7', 'function_6', 'function_2', 'function_4', 'function_7', 'function_2', 'function_5', 'function_7', 'function_1', 'function_2', 'function_5', 'function_5', 'function_5', 'function_3', 'function_3', 'function_3', 'function_3'],
'country_code' : ['country3', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country1', 'country9', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country2', 'country1', 'country1', 'country5', 'country1', 'country5', 'country5', 'country12', 'country9', 'country3', 'country2', 'country3', 'country1', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country9', 'country3', 'country1', 'country2', 'country1', 'country9', 'country1', 'country3', 'country9', 'country1', 'country9', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country3', 'country4', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country6', 'country1', 'country1', 'country9', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country3', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1', 'country9', 'country1', 'country1', 'country6', 'country14', 'country4', 'country10', 'country10', 'country14', 'country1', 'country1', 'country1'],
'employee_id' : ['emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3', 'emp4', 'emp5', 'emp6', 'emp7', 'emp2', 'emp1', 'emp6', 'emp8', 'emp3', 'emp1', 'emp6', 'emp8', 'emp2', 'emp7', 'emp4', 'emp8', 'emp5', 'emp8', 'emp4', 'emp1', 'emp9', 'emp7', 'emp4', 'emp5', 'emp1', 'emp8', 'emp2', 'emp8', 'emp4', 'emp2', 'emp6', 'emp4', 'emp10', 'emp6', 'emp10', 'emp10', 'emp9', 'emp10', 'emp4', 'emp9', 'emp8', 'emp5', 'emp8', 'emp3', 'emp6', 'emp3', 'emp6', 'emp2', 'emp6', 'emp1', 'emp2', 'emp3', 'emp6', 'emp6', 'emp2', 'emp6', 'emp1', 'emp6', 'emp6', 'emp6', 'emp3', 'emp8', 'emp1', 'emp8', 'emp8', 'emp2', 'emp6', 'emp3', 'emp6', 'emp8', 'emp1', 'emp10', 'emp1', 'emp8', 'emp6', 'emp8', 'emp2', 'emp1', 'emp2', 'emp6', 'emp8', 'emp8', 'emp8', 'emp2', 'emp6', 'emp8', 'emp10', 'emp6', 'emp1', 'emp11', 'emp12', 'emp13', 'emp13', 'emp14', 'emp14', 'emp14', 'emp14'],
'time_created' : ['2023-06-17 20:14:17.311', '2023-06-17 20:18:12.232', '2023-06-17 20:21:49.917', '2023-06-17 20:24:02.617', '2023-06-17 20:26:50.739', '2023-06-17 20:26:43.510', '2023-06-17 20:27:38.979', '2023-06-17 20:28:40.599', '2023-06-17 20:30:57.405', '2023-06-17 20:30:38.544', '2023-06-17 20:40:23.902', '2023-06-17 20:42:00.869', '2023-06-17 20:39:44.346', '2023-06-17 20:43:40.614', '2023-06-17 20:38:46.621', '2023-06-17 20:45:46.476', '2023-06-17 20:46:07.558', '2023-06-17 20:55:13.492', '2023-06-17 20:56:01.564', '2023-06-17 21:00:49.596', '2023-06-17 20:57:31.688', '2023-06-17 21:02:03.657', '2023-06-17 21:02:19.180', '2023-06-17 21:00:50.673', '2023-06-17 21:08:32.449', '2023-06-17 21:08:22.179', '2023-06-17 21:15:18.588', '2023-06-17 21:21:47.750', '2023-06-17 21:25:11.048', '2023-06-17 21:25:48.403', '2023-06-17 21:27:56.747', '2023-06-17 21:32:05.291', '2023-06-17 21:34:34.751', '2023-06-17 21:37:03.961', '2023-06-17 21:41:01.666', '2023-06-17 17:57:29.438', '2023-06-17 21:38:16.714', '2023-06-17 18:05:29.199', '2023-06-17 18:19:04.931', '2023-06-17 21:41:01.773', '2023-06-17 20:28:33.795', '2023-06-17 21:45:43.000', '2023-06-17 21:45:18.882', '2023-06-17 21:50:28.857', '2023-06-17 21:54:48.772', '2023-06-17 21:54:54.044', '2023-06-17 21:55:10.374', '2023-06-17 22:03:00.272', '2023-06-17 22:06:05.007', '2023-06-17 22:04:44.732', '2023-06-17 22:06:07.945', '2023-06-17 22:09:44.790', '2023-06-17 22:19:09.983', '2023-06-17 22:15:19.572', '2023-06-17 22:21:14.828', '2023-06-17 22:21:41.157', '2023-06-17 22:23:06.036', '2023-06-17 22:27:19.070', '2023-06-17 22:27:03.854', '2023-06-17 22:28:53.296', '2023-06-17 22:33:52.264', '2023-06-17 22:34:57.518', '2023-06-17 22:47:40.202', '2023-06-17 22:47:58.102', '2023-06-17 22:47:58.550', '2023-06-17 22:49:41.546', '2023-06-17 22:49:46.063', '2023-06-17 22:50:08.812', '2023-06-17 22:52:23.236', '2023-06-17 22:56:37.736', '2023-06-17 22:59:06.817', '2023-06-17 23:04:01.269', '2023-06-17 23:07:13.322', '2023-06-17 22:56:48.799', '2023-06-17 22:39:13.389', '2023-06-17 23:12:28.034', '2023-06-17 23:14:32.697', '2023-06-17 23:20:10.653', '2023-06-17 23:23:01.957', '2023-06-17 23:23:32.825', '2023-06-17 23:30:58.160', '2023-06-17 23:22:14.980', '2023-06-17 23:31:14.529', '2023-06-17 23:31:40.861', '2023-06-17 23:36:09.446', '2023-06-17 23:47:19.173', '2023-06-17 23:28:27.466', '2023-06-17 23:49:43.044', '2023-06-17 23:28:35.754', '2023-06-17 23:55:38.878', '2023-06-17 23:56:38.590', '2023-06-17 23:44:06.839', '2023-06-17 15:38:59.886', '2023-06-17 11:42:29.640', '2023-06-17 11:32:01.165', '2023-06-17 16:06:55.354', '2023-06-17 07:44:01.391', '2023-06-17 15:01:03.617', '2023-06-17 17:06:05.529', '2023-06-17 19:06:21.295'],
'time_assigned' : ['2023-06-17 20:15:04.319', '2023-06-17 20:18:36.504', '2023-06-17 20:21:51.155', '2023-06-17 20:27:12.338', '2023-06-17 20:28:01.803', '2023-06-17 20:29:08.918', '2023-06-17 20:32:30.227', '2023-06-17 20:32:39.857', '2023-06-17 20:33:53.921', '2023-06-17 20:36:02.392', '2023-06-17 20:41:18.113', '2023-06-17 20:42:59.638', '2023-06-17 20:43:09.292', '2023-06-17 20:45:15.437', '2023-06-17 20:45:22.236', '2023-06-17 20:46:06.525', '2023-06-17 20:46:14.485', '2023-06-17 20:55:30.275', '2023-06-17 20:56:09.985', '2023-06-17 21:01:15.087', '2023-06-17 21:02:48.466', '2023-06-17 21:02:48.822', '2023-06-17 21:02:55.819', '2023-06-17 21:04:25.885', '2023-06-17 21:09:05.480', '2023-06-17 21:13:00.095', '2023-06-17 21:21:06.182', '2023-06-17 21:22:41.290', '2023-06-17 21:26:24.277', '2023-06-17 21:26:44.479', '2023-06-17 21:29:08.258', '2023-06-17 21:34:00.114', '2023-06-17 21:35:57.838', '2023-06-17 21:38:26.939', '2023-06-17 21:41:22.903', '2023-06-17 21:42:51.774', '2023-06-17 21:43:30.574', '2023-06-17 21:44:22.396', '2023-06-17 21:45:07.438', '2023-06-17 21:45:37.287', '2023-06-17 21:45:48.680', '2023-06-17 21:46:52.541', '2023-06-17 21:50:24.423', '2023-06-17 21:52:47.105', '2023-06-17 21:54:52.303', '2023-06-17 21:56:52.651', '2023-06-17 21:56:56.528', '2023-06-17 22:03:25.218', '2023-06-17 22:06:36.079', '2023-06-17 22:07:40.839', '2023-06-17 22:11:55.120', '2023-06-17 22:16:09.169', '2023-06-17 22:19:43.147', '2023-06-17 22:20:24.109', '2023-06-17 22:21:31.828', '2023-06-17 22:23:27.157', '2023-06-17 22:26:16.273', '2023-06-17 22:27:51.741', '2023-06-17 22:29:27.678', '2023-06-17 22:29:39.063', '2023-06-17 22:35:30.515', '2023-06-17 22:38:40.255', '2023-06-17 22:47:46.807', '2023-06-17 22:48:28.767', '2023-06-17 22:48:29.899', '2023-06-17 22:50:00.869', '2023-06-17 22:50:07.991', '2023-06-17 22:53:23.839', '2023-06-17 22:53:28.796', '2023-06-17 22:58:05.570', '2023-06-17 23:01:11.459', '2023-06-17 23:06:35.475', '2023-06-17 23:10:00.280', '2023-06-17 23:12:26.824', '2023-06-17 23:14:00.761', '2023-06-17 23:14:02.275', '2023-06-17 23:18:30.538', '2023-06-17 23:20:41.619', '2023-06-17 23:28:43.162', '2023-06-17 23:29:37.107', '2023-06-17 23:31:24.097', '2023-06-17 23:31:56.054', '2023-06-17 23:31:57.824', '2023-06-17 23:34:37.704', '2023-06-17 23:42:19.000', '2023-06-17 23:48:35.095', '2023-06-17 23:49:57.602', '2023-06-17 23:50:05.353', '2023-06-17 23:51:07.026', '2023-06-17 23:57:56.296', '2023-06-17 23:59:01.553', '2023-06-18 01:10:13.441', '2023-06-18 01:20:43.506', '2023-06-18 04:25:35.884', '2023-06-18 09:43:13.344', '2023-06-18 09:44:45.123', '2023-06-18 11:53:07.047', '2023-06-18 11:54:02.087', '2023-06-18 11:55:45.177', '2023-06-18 11:57:43.830'],
'time_closed' : ['2023-06-17 20:20:31.137', '2023-06-17 20:23:31.117', '2023-06-17 20:28:08.333', '2023-06-17 20:36:30.223', '2023-06-17 20:31:05.252', '2023-06-17 20:35:27.100', '2023-06-17 20:35:51.635', '2023-06-17 20:37:58.641', '2023-06-17 20:37:18.241', '2023-06-17 20:39:35.518', '2023-06-17 20:45:17.265', '2023-06-17 20:47:56.438', '2023-06-17 20:48:08.085', '2023-06-17 20:52:07.462', '2023-06-17 20:49:31.387', '2023-06-17 20:50:19.867', '2023-06-17 20:54:43.217', '2023-06-17 20:59:05.857', '2023-06-17 21:00:14.904', '2023-06-17 21:05:58.286', '2023-06-17 21:09:19.817', '2023-06-17 21:06:14.715', '2023-06-17 21:07:30.307', '2023-06-17 21:06:11.474', '2023-06-17 21:12:11.986', '2023-06-17 21:16:29.860', '2023-06-17 21:24:08.914', '2023-06-17 21:32:29.255', '2023-06-17 21:28:56.732', '2023-06-17 21:31:43.205', '2023-06-17 21:30:36.539', '2023-06-17 21:37:06.879', '2023-06-17 21:39:10.565', '2023-06-17 21:43:17.005', '2023-06-17 21:44:30.360', '2023-06-17 21:43:51.222', '2023-06-17 21:47:52.677', '2023-06-17 21:44:57.522', '2023-06-17 21:45:43.180', '2023-06-17 21:48:09.917', '2023-06-17 21:46:14.039', '2023-06-17 21:49:50.680', '2023-06-17 21:52:09.533', '2023-06-17 21:56:49.093', '2023-06-17 21:58:12.870', '2023-06-17 21:58:39.697', '2023-06-17 22:03:28.664', '2023-06-17 22:07:30.328', '2023-06-17 22:11:56.199', '2023-06-17 22:16:02.822', '2023-06-17 22:14:33.618', '2023-06-17 22:19:09.961', '2023-06-17 22:25:23.768', '2023-06-17 22:25:21.741', '2023-06-17 22:30:12.860', '2023-06-17 22:26:06.134', '2023-06-17 22:29:17.436', '2023-06-17 22:31:15.628', '2023-06-17 22:31:38.816', '2023-06-17 22:33:41.970', '2023-06-17 22:38:31.387', '2023-06-17 22:43:06.899', '2023-06-17 22:51:55.411', '2023-06-17 22:52:57.830', '2023-06-17 22:50:03.305', '2023-06-17 22:55:41.605', '2023-06-17 22:53:19.549', '2023-06-17 22:55:27.440', '2023-06-17 22:59:39.774', '2023-06-17 23:03:54.050', '2023-06-17 23:06:07.888', '2023-06-17 23:08:52.646', '2023-06-17 23:13:22.386', '2023-06-17 23:12:54.268', '2023-06-17 23:14:33.900', '2023-06-17 23:17:59.087', '2023-06-17 23:28:39.801', '2023-06-17 23:24:25.467', '2023-06-17 23:34:34.307', '2023-06-17 23:31:36.533', '2023-06-17 23:42:27.253', '2023-06-17 23:38:36.862', '2023-06-17 23:37:38.303', '2023-06-17 23:39:50.893', '2023-06-17 23:48:30.849', '2023-06-17 23:51:00.421', '2023-06-17 23:51:00.132', '2023-06-17 23:54:26.615', '2023-06-17 23:52:19.068', '2023-06-18 00:05:11.267', '2023-06-18 00:03:32.152', '2023-06-18 01:10:40.385', '2023-06-18 01:21:10.944', '2023-06-18 04:26:30.131', '2023-06-18 09:44:37.892', '2023-06-18 09:45:18.282', '2023-06-18 11:53:55.331', '2023-06-18 11:55:37.832', '2023-06-18 11:57:39.497', '2023-06-18 11:59:01.326'],
'countries' : ['country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country3, country2, country4, country5', 'country3, country9, country1, country12, country5, country2, country4, country10', 'country9, country1, country3, country2, country5, country13, country12', 'country1, country5', 'country5, country1, country3, country6, country2, country11, country10, country8', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country3, country2, country4, country5', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country5, country1, country3, country6, country2, country11, country10, country8', 'country3, country9, country1, country12, country5, country2, country4, country10', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country9, country1, country3, country2, country5, country13, country12', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country3, country9, country1, country12, country5, country2, country4, country10', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country9, country5, country2, country3, country1, country12, country4, country10, country6', 'country5, country1, country3, country6, country2, country11, country10, country8', 'country3, country9, country1, country12, country5, country2, country4, country10', 'country9, country1, country3, country2, country5, country13, country12', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country3, country9, country1, country12, country5, country2, country4, country10', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country3, country9, country1, country12, country5, country2, country4, country10', 'country1, country2, country3, country8', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country2, country3, country8', 'country1, country2, country3, country8', 'country9, country5, country2, country3, country1, country12, country4, country10, country6', 'country1, country2, country3, country8', 'country3, country9, country1, country12, country5, country2, country4, country10', 'country9, country5, country2, country3, country1, country12, country4, country10, country6', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country9, country1, country3, country2, country5, country13, country12', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country3, country2, country4, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country3, country2, country4, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country3, country2, country4, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country3, country2, country4, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country3, country2, country4, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country2, country3, country8', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country3, country4, country2, country5', 'country1, country5', 'country1, country9, country2, country10, country3, country5', 'country1, country2, country3, country8', 'country1, country5', 'country6, country3, country1, country2, country5, country10, country8, country4, country7', 'country14', 'country4', 'country10, country2, country1, country12, country9, country13', 'country10, country2, country1, country12, country9, country13', 'country1, country14, country10, country3, country15, country6, country4, country2, country5, country11', 'country1, country14, country10, country3, country15, country6, country4, country2, country5, country11', 'country1, country14, country10, country3, country15, country6, country4, country2, country5, country11', 'country1, country14, country10, country3, country15, country6, country4, country2, country5, country11'],
'functions' : ['function_1, function_2', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_2, function_1, function_6, function_4', 'function_2, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_1, function_4, function_5', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_4, function_1', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_1, function_6, function_4', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_2, function_4, function_1', 'function_2, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_1, function_4, function_5', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_2, function_6, function_1, function_4', 'function_2, function_4, function_1', 'function_2, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_1, function_4, function_5', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_5', 'function_7', 'function_5', 'function_5', 'function_2, function_6, function_1, function_4', 'function_5', 'function_2, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_6, function_1, function_4', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_1, function_4, function_5', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_1, function_6, function_4', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_1, function_6, function_4', 'function_7', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_7', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_2, function_1, function_6, function_4', 'function_7', 'function_7', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_7', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_7', 'function_7', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_1, function_6, function_4', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_1, function_6, function_4', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_5', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_4, function_2, function_1', 'function_7', 'function_2, function_6, function_7, function_4, function_1, function_5', 'function_5', 'function_7', 'function_1, function_2', 'function_2, function_4', 'function_5', 'function_5, function_2, function_1, function_4, function_3', 'function_5, function_2, function_1, function_4, function_3', 'function_3', 'function_3', 'function_3', 'function_3']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data)

df1['time_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time_created'])
df1['time_assigned'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time_assigned'])
df1['time_closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time_closed'])

# Defining a function to fetch the relevant data
def get_next_task_assign_creation_time(row):

    # Limit time for the data to max 10 days from closing the last task
    ten_days=timedelta(hours=240)
    
    # Get the necessary parameters from the row
    task_id=row['task_id']
    login=row['employee_id']
    time_closed=row['time_closed']

    # set the max time limit for time_assigned
    upper_time_limit=time_closed+ten_days

    # create array of functions and stores
    func= [s.strip() for s in row['functions'].split(',')]
    countries= [s.strip() for s in row['countries'].split(',')]

    # progressively filter the df1
    
    t_df=df1[(df1['employee_id']==login)]  
    t_df=t_df[t_df['time_assigned']>=time_closed] 
    t_df=t_df[t_df['time_assigned']<=upper_time_limit]
    t_df=t_df[(t_df['function'].str.strip().isin(func)) ]  
    t_df=t_df[(t_df['country_code'].str.strip().isin(countries))]

    # finding the time_assigned value 
    next_task_time=t_df['time_assigned'].min()

    return next_task_time

# Update the next_task_pickup_time value
df1['next_task_pickup_time']=df1.apply(get_next_task_assign_creation_time,axis=1)
```

The expected output is a column containing dictionary as shown below

```
'next_task_details=["{'request_id': 'request_1001', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:33:53.921000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:30:57.405000')}", "{'request_id': 'request_1002', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:32:39.857000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:28:40.599000')}", "{'request_id': 'request_1003', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:42:59.638000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:42:00.869000')}", "{'request_id': 'request_1004', 'next_task_pickup_time': NaT, 'next_task_creation_time': NaT}", "{'request_id': 'request_1005', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 21:01:15.087000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 21:00:49.596000')}", "{'request_id': 'request_1006', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:36:02.392000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:30:38.544000')}", "{'request_id': 'request_1007', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:46:14.485000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:46:07.558000')}", "{'request_id': 'request_1008', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:46:06.525000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:45:46.476000')}", "{'request_id': 'request_1009', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:43:09.292000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:39:44.346000')}", "{'request_id': 'request_1010', 'next_task_pickup_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:45:15.437000'), 'next_task_creation_time': Timestamp('2023-06-17 20:43:40.614000')}",
```

This approach takes very complete (like 4 hours for 100000 rows). I believe row wise iteration is very slow, and vectorization can make this a much faster. I am seeking help to understand if I can apply vectorization instead of applying the function row-wise .

Can anyone please share their thoughts / suggestion on vectorizing the above process, or any other possible approach?

Comment: can you show expected output?

Comment: Output for first set of rows added. Missed the rest because the 3000-word limitation in stackoverflow

Comment: Am I right that the code you posted is _correct_ but _slow_?

Comment: this seems like the perfect candidate for going on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: also, "I need to pick the next task picked by the employee from the last 'stores' and 'functions' values" <- can you clarify if you are wanting to pick the next task for the employee, or "find the time at which an employee picked a new task after closing the current one", or both?

Comment: also, you never define get_open_tasks_at_close

Comment: and you have 'request_id' in your function but not in your sample code

Comment: can you clarify - 1. can employees work across multiple stores? 2. multiple countries? 3. can an employee do tasks at any stores within a country?

Comment: I think a decent part of the slowness of your code OP is the messy state the business has left the data in. If you clean up the data, that ought to get you a decent speedup (if not, it would help clarify things

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests if you can) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: Please show us your full Python code which we can try ourselves. Without that we can only guess e.g. what `get_open_tasks_at_close` is doing.

Comment: *> this is taking for ever to complete on a sample dataset of 100000 rows*

What full code do you run? What is the sample dataset (can you share a copy)? Exactly how long does it take? If you don't provide details, we can only guess.

Comment: Prcessing 100000 rows in Python can take less than a second, depending on how much work you have to do per row. Maybe you are doing O(n**2) operations, but O(n*log(n)) should be enough, if a better algorithm was used. It's impossible for us to tell, until you show us a full code example, which we can run ourselves.

Comment: @Vitalizzare - Yes, the code I pasted is correct but very slow

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for taking the time to point out the misses. My apologies. While creating the sample data and code, made a lot of mistakes, leading to mismatches and errors that you pointed out. I have corrected them in the edited post

Comment: @Mark - 1. can employees work across multiple stores? Yes 2. multiple countries? Yes 3. can an employee do tasks at any stores within a country? Yes

Comment: @Mark - also, "I need to pick the next task picked by the employee from the last 'stores' and 'functions' values" <- can you clarify if you are wanting to pick the next task for the employee, or "find the time at which an employee picked a new task after closing the current one", or both?
I want to find the time at which the employee picked a new task after closing the current one

Comment: @pts - get_open_tasks_at_close has been replaced with the correct function

Comment: I notice your code references a column named functions: `row['functions']`. However, there is no functions column in your test data, so I get a KeyError. Is there supposed to be a column called functions in the data?

Comment: @NickODell - apologies for the miss. Updated

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would suggest that's pretty low-hanging fruit is to group by employee.

From what I can see of your code, each employee's results are independent of every other employee's results. You can split each up and process them separately.

Why does that matter? You call the following code once for each row:

```
t_df=df1[(df1['employee_id']==login)]
```

This requires searching the entire dataframe for rows with the same employee. This is an O(N^2) operation, so it'll be slow. But it also means that subdividing the problem will make it faster.

Imagine you have 1,000 rows with 10 employees. An O(N^2) algorithm takes a 1,000,000 steps to solve this. But if you split it up into one part for each employee, that's only (100^2 * 10) = 100,000 steps. The exact speedup will depend on how many employees there are. If you have a small number of employees, then this may not be worth doing.

```
def process_employee_df(employee_df):
    def get_next_task_assign_creation_time(row):

        # Limit time for the data to max 10 days from closing the last task
        ten_days=timedelta(hours=240)

        # Get the necessary parameters from the row
        task_id=row['task_id']
        login=row['employee_id']
        time_closed=row['time_closed']

        # set the max time limit for time_assigned
        upper_time_limit=time_closed+ten_days

        # create array of functions and stores
        func= [s.strip() for s in row['functions'].split(',')]
        countries= [s.strip() for s in row['countries'].split(',')]

        # progressively filter the df1

        t_df=employee_df
        t_df=t_df[t_df['time_assigned']>=time_closed] 
        t_df=t_df[t_df['time_assigned']<=upper_time_limit]
        t_df=t_df[(t_df['function'].str.strip().isin(func)) ]  
        t_df=t_df[(t_df['country_code'].str.strip().isin(countries))]

        # finding the time_assigned value 
        next_task_time=t_df['time_assigned'].min()
        return next_task_time
    return employee_df.apply(get_next_task_assign_creation_time, axis=1)

df1.groupby(['employee_id']).apply(process_employee_df).droplevel(0).sort_index()
```

Comment: Indeed, this speeds it up from O(n**2) in the question to O(n). The speedup looks like sufficient.